# Loop through subrecords in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a nested datasheet, where *bar* is the child of *foo*.

To loop through all records of *foo*, I would simply do

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Forms!foo.Form.RecordsetClone

Do Until rst.EOF
    'Do Something
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

But now I want to loop through all records of its child form *bar*. I tried

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim subrst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Forms!foo.Form.RecordsetClone

Do Until rst.EOF
    Set subrst = Forms!foo.Form!bar.Form.RecordsetClone

    Do Until subrst.EOF
        'Do Something
        subrst.MoveNext
    Loop
rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Sadly this only loops through the subrecords of the very first record. All other subrecords are never reached. How do I access the recordset of all other subrecords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation you have is the subrecords belonging to the current (visible) record of the parent record.

To retrieve the remaining subrecords, either move the record on the main form (use Bookmark) or open the recordsource of the subform and loop this filtering on the key of the parent record in the current loop (of "foo").

Comment: So if I take your first suggestion I'd need to do `Me.Bookmark=rst.Bookmark` after `rst.MoveNext`? Is it bad style to instead move through the displayed recordset without a clone?

Comment: It is bad style to manipulate the UI only to count records, and much slower too, when it easily can be done both silently and faster and with code of similar volume and complexity.